# Should I use Javascript Bookmarklets or something else to perform a basic form fill task?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning Python and understand how to use CSS Selectors to do basic web scraping and form input.

My understanding is Python Selenium is good for running a project in the background but not so much for doing specific short tasks as you're working within a web browser.

I am trying to do the task on an individual basis in an existing browser, not create an entire new browser object and iterate through multiple forms.

Would making a bookmarklet with Javascript be a good idea or should I look into AutoHotKey or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bookmarklets and desktop automation would both work. The benefit of bookmarklets is that you can take them with you to other platforms, if you sync your browser bookmarks with other devices with your Google or Firefox account you could use them on macOS, Linux, or BSD as well. They're also fairly easy to write, and there are various bookmarket shrinkers online like [this one](https://caiorss.github.io/bookmarklet-maker/) and [this one](https://bookmarklets.org/maker/) so you can write in regular JS and boomarketlet-ify them later.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with this? I believe this line identifies the input field. What do I have to write to actually submit the information? Not a variable, same text every time. `phonefield = document.querySelector('input[name="phone"]')`

Comment: `phonefield.value = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'` to fill in the field, and then `document.querySelector('form').submit()` to actually submit the form. if there's more than one `form` on the page you may need to use a more specific selector like you are with the `name` attribute on the `input` selector, or use `phonefield.closest('form')` which should usually be the correct one. An example using StackOverflow's search: `search = document.querySelector('input[name=q]');search.value = 'javascript';search.closest('form').submit();`